# How do you export default from inside script setup in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

The export default statement does not seem to work inside `<script setup>`.

If I try to export it in `test.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="test" class="test">

  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
const x = 5

export default {
    x
}
</script>


<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

and then importing it into another `blog.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import x from './test'
</script>
```

I am getting this bulk of error:

```
app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:37396 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'content')
    at selectBlock (:3000/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/select.js:23:45)
    at Object.loader (:3000/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js:67:41)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:37396:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806:42)
    at Module../resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:60116:217)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806:42)
    at Module../resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:59477:102)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806:42)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/backend/components/blog.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:37336:63)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806:42)
    at Module../resources/vue/backend/components/blog.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:60084:217)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806:42)
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:37396
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:60116
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/vue/backend/components/test.vue @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:59477
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/backend/components/blog.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:37336
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/vue/backend/components/blog.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:60084
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/vue/backend/components/blog.vue @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:59328
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/js/router.js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:39847
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:39770
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64806
(anonymous) @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64971
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64843
(anonymous) @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64973
(anonymous) @ app.js?id=3b6365f542826af47b926162803b3ef6:64975
```

Comment: The purpose of script setup is to skip boilerplate code. This includes 'export default'. It's a component that is expected to be exported from .vue as default. Consider explaining what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was thinking that there might be a time when I want to export a global js function from a vue component but I understand it being a fringe case.

Comment: Yes. In case reusable code is needed, .js file is the best place for it, not .vue

Comment: unsure but maybe this is what you are after: [vue defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

Answer (score 4):

You can maybe use this method.

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'xxxComponent',
})
</script>
<script setup>
    const x = ref(5)
    // computed
    const computedVariable = computed(() => {
        return object.variable
    })
    // methods
    const updateModalCookieInitialOpenMethod = (val) => {
        cookies.updateCookieSettings(val)
        cookies.updateModalCookieInitialOpen()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Create new file `*.d.ts` like `vue.d.ts` or paste script below this `vite-env.d.ts` file (generate by vite)

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const component: DefineComponent<Record<string, unknown>, Record<string, unknown>, any>;
  export default component;
}
```

and then you can use `script setup>` without defining two script tags

Comment: Super clean, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this marked as answered so here's what I found dealing with same issue:

You can just use regular  block alongside the  block and place your export in that.

Here is the relevant documentation: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `defineOPtions` I had the a similar problem where without the setup script I would done the following

```
<script>
import AnotherLayout from "../layouts/Another.vue"
export default {
layout: AnotherLayout
}
</script>
```

With the setup script, you have to use the following syntax.

```
<script setup>
import AnotherLayout from "../layouts/Another.vue"
defineOptions({
  layout: Another
})
</script>
```

See the VueJS Docs for more info https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineoptions

Answer (score 0):

'Components using `script setup` are closed by default' - said from their own docs.

You need to expose using `defineExpose()`

```
<script setup>

const x = 5;

defineExpose({
  x
})
</script>
```

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

Comment: Almost correct, the correct property to use is `defineOptions` see my answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741801/501827

Answer (score -3):

Hello i just see from others and it went well for me. Just add name properties next to script setup and it will export your component.

```
<script setup name="Greet">
</script>
```

it is the same as

```
 export const MyComponent = {
 name: "MyComponent" // I'm not 100% set on this part}
```

So you can just add your code in the parent component like this.

```
<script setup>
 import Greet from './components/Greet.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <Greet/>
</template>
```